# ComRegisterFunction not worked

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, com

i'll try to implement `IShellIconOverlayIdentifier` interface for setting icon overlays.

But code in `ComRegisterFunction` not worked:

```
[ComRegisterFunction]
public static void Register(Type t)
{
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"
    + t.Name + @"\");
    rk.SetValue(string.Empty, t.GUID.ToString("B").ToUpper());
    rk.Close();
    ShellInterop.SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

After registration threre is no my key in Registry.  If i call the same code from othere application it’s work correct. But with `Regasm` not worked.

Comment: Using the wrong version of Regasm.exe is a pretty standard mistake.  Look in SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\... instead.  If you see it there then use the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe instead.  Exactly why you are doing this is very unclear, Regasm.exe ought to be used to register [ComVisible] classes and you are not doing this at all.  Just writing a console mode app with a manifest that gives you UAC elevation is the simpler approach.

Comment: My class is ComVisible. I do it to register additional information for Shell extention(Icon Handler)